# How to drag line between list of items in Controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to drag a line between country and its region in dropdown list.

This is the code where I want to drag a line in end of   `new SelectListItem {Value = "GB", Text = "Great Britain" }` like `-----------------`. Please guide me. Thank you in advance.

```
 RacingRegionsOptions = new List<SelectListItem>
            {

              new SelectListItem {Value = "NZ", Text="New Zealand" },
              new SelectListItem {Value = "AUS", Text = "Australia" },
              new SelectListItem {Value = "FR", Text = "France" },
              new SelectListItem {Value = "GB", Text = "Great Britain" },


            new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Australia & New 
              Zealand" },
              new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "South East Asia" },
              new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "Principal Europe" },
              new SelectListItem {Value = "4", Text = "All Europe" },
              new SelectListItem {Value = "5", Text = "Soutern Hemisphere" },

        }
```

Comment: Do you mean _"**draw** a line"_ rather then _"**drag** a line"_? If not, what does _"drag a line"_ mean?

Comment: @stuartd, Yes, I mean draw a line. Because I want to differentiate by drawing a line.

Comment: You may also use `optgroup` to group items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the most clean solution would be use a JS library on your View that implements a *item divider*, (such as [Select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#single-select-boxes)) but if you **really** want to implement on your server SelectList, you can try this:

```
 new SelectListItem {Value = "", Text = "---------------------------", Disabled = true },
```

(I don't really think this is a good idea)

Answer (score 1):

You may consider rendering the SELECT options using `optgroup`. The `optgroup` element creates a grouping of options within a select element. The `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method supports rendering select element with optgroup!

```
var other = new SelectListGroup() {Name = "------Other----"};
var items = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem {Value = "NZ", Text = "New Zealand"},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "AUS", Text = "Australia"},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "FR", Text = "France"},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "GB", Text = "Great Britain"},

    new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Australia & New Zealand", Group = other},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "South East Asia", Group = other},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "Principal Europe", Group = other},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "4", Text = "All Europe", Group = other},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "5", Text = "Soutern Hemisphere", Group = other}
};
// Use items variable to initialize to set the value of RacingRegionsOptions
```

This will wrap the last 5 items inside an `optgroup` which has the label `------Other----`.

optgroup is used to group the option items in the UI. User cannot select the group as the selected option.